# Creating custom geometry on Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to include the snapshot for each issue which includes the highlighted issue with the complete plan, which I intend to use in a custom report. The files are in PDF format for the plan.

Now, the optimal workflow which I feel would be the following:
1) Create a custom geometry (circle) at the issue location.
2) Take a snapshot of the viewer and save it at a location

I have been trying the below code for step 1:

```
var pushpinAttributes = issue.attributes.pushpin_attributes;
var viewer = viewerApp.getCurrentViewer();
var geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
sphereMesh.position.set(pushpinAttributes.location.x, pushpinAttributes.location.y, pushpinAttributes.location.z);
viewer.impl.createOverlayScene ('overlay-scene', material);
viewer.impl.addOverlay('overlay-scene', sphereMesh);
viewer.impl.invalidate (true);
```

For step 2, I am using viewer.getScreenShot();

However, the geometry is created at a different location than that of the pushpin.

Where could I be going wrong?
Is there be a better way of doing the same?

Comment: The location of pushpin from Issue should be in the model coordination. I did a quick test by https://bim360issues.herokuapp.com/. This demo grabs the pushpin info by Issue API. I got out the pushpin locations and run your code, it looks the sphere locates in the same position. Can I know which version of Viewer you are using? it happens with specific model or any model?

Comment: Currently, I am using v6 of the viewer. Could that be causing an issue ?
The issues are currently marked on the pdf files.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I missed your reply. I can reproduce this issue. It looks it requires page coordination with 2D sheet with custom geometry. I will investigate and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for extending your help @XiaodongLiang. I really appreciate this.

Comment: Debugging pushpin extension, I finally found this is not issue of 2D sheet only, instead, it is because PDF by Model Derivative of Forge is converted to leaflet, which requires transformation between leaflet view (client) and pushpin location. This screenshot is my test: paste.pics/3f3a2464ff560307c0e492b9596c0d2d. In pushpin extension (actually in PushpinUtils.js), it has a function worldToClient, but I do not see the same function (same arguments) exposed. I will check with engineer team

Comment: Hi @XiaodongLiang, Did you have a chance to check with the engineer?
I tried using the worldToClient() function for the viewer(located in Viewer3D.js). However, it didn't seem to work. 
var testCoordinates = viewer.worldToClient(pushpinAttributes.location);
https://paste.pics/2039f4cd0a9a0bf3f22d97c630433489
The same function is available in PushPinUtils.js as well but with different parameters. Should I be using the function available in PushPinUtils.js to achieve my purpose and not from Viewer3D.js?

Comment: My apology for the delay! Our engineer team told me `worldToClient` inside PushpinUtils.js is an internal method that is being used by the pushpin extension, in order to convert pushpins that belongs to Vector-PDFs / Leaflets from world coordinates, to client coordinates. This function is not public because it’s part of the internal flow of parsing and transforming of the pushpins. I will have to log a wish.

Comment: finally the ticket has been logged: LMV-5133

Comment: Thanks for your support !